# Best way to 'store' single bytes in objective c variables

Tags: objective-c, byte, bit

I need to store single bytes in objective c. So I may have a class interface like this:

```
@interface NAD : NSObject

@property (...) ... byte;

@end
```

I started off with `uint8_t` pointers, but this was getting difficult because they're actually 4 bytes, or something.

So I switched to using `NSData`. But `NSData` deals in "bytes" (plural). This isn't a problem necessarily, but is getting quite fiddly having to convert between all the time.

So is there a better way to store 1 byte (8 bits) in objective c variables?

Many thanks

Comment: A `uint8_t` _pointer_ may be 4 bytes, but a `uint8_t` will be 8 bits exactly. Why do you need a pointer, and if it is a pointer why do you care how many bits the pointer representation itself is?

Comment: A `char` is exactly one byte in the C standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `uint8_t *` and not simply `uint8_t`?

```
@property (assign) uint8_t byte;
```

To wrap it into an NSData object:

```
uint8_t b = object.byte;
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:&b length:1];
```

Comment: How would I convert `uint8_t` to `char void *` for use in `NSData` objects?

Comment: They're compatible, so you can just take the address (*`&self.byte`*). But why do you want to wrap it into `NSData`?

Comment: I need to combine it into an `NSData` object to send to a bluetooth device. `NSData` stores the length of data with the bytes you see. When I do `[data appendBytes:&_nad.byte length:1];` I get the error `Address of property expression requested`.